# objects in a sprite.Group() not behaving as unique objects as they should

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, sprite

Below is the troubling code with a quick breakdown.

```
if player.attacked == True and delay >= 60: #if it's monster's turn plus a built in delay so everything isn't instant
    for enemy in enemies_list: #iterating the all the enemies in the sprite group
        if enemy.attack_rdy == True and enemy.health >0 and delay ==60: #if THAT particular monster hasn't attacked, isn't dead, and the delay has been long enough.
            player.hit.play() #play the player's damaged sound
            damage = random.randrange(each.attack[0],each.attack[1]+1)-player.armor #random attack roll of a tuple assigned to the enemy class
            player.health -= damage 
            enemy.attack_rdy = False #Sets THIS particular enemy so that he may not attack until it's his turn again
            player.damaged = True #Just triggers an animation on the player
            each.attack_anim = 1 #triggers an animation on the enemy
            break #stops the for loop so that everything doesn't happen at once and relies on the delay int.
```

**Problem:**
This iteration works properly in that the player is accurately attacked the correct number of times in accordance to the number of enemies attacking him. For some weird reason the same enemy will be attacking all those times however. When the attacking enemy dies, another one simply takes over his task of being the one who attacks. I can make no sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

In true bonehead fashion, after staring at and editing my code for hours I find my blunder mere moments after posting. It's really just a stupid error.

```
each.attack_anim = 1
```

SHOULD read

```
enemy.attack_anim = 1
```

With blunder corrected, code runs as designed.